# Why can't i loop through this stack?

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to make a parentheses checker with implementing stack. The program will print valid if the input have a correct parentheses pattern

```
input: {[()]}
output: valid

input: {()[()]}
output: valid

input: (()))
output: unvalid

continuously
```

But what happen after i input the data is :

```
()
the program prints this unlimited loop
valid
valid
valid
valid
valid
. . . and so on

same with
(()))
```

It works normally if put break; on here, but it won't be continuous and would instantly ends the program, and wont ask for the input again.

```
if(isempty(stack)){
    printf("Valid parenthesis expression\n");
    break;
} else{
     printf("Invalid parenthesis expression\n");
     break;
}
```

I can't seem to find the reason why this happened,
can anyone help me or give me some advice about what's going on? So that I can loop to ask for input and print the valid/invalid just only one time?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct data{

    char parent;
    struct data *next;

}DATA;

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses);
int isempty(DATA *stack);
void pop(DATA **stack);
int top(DATA *stack);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    DATA *stack;
    char parentheses[100];
    int i, flag = 1;
    do{
        //PUSH
        stack = NULL;

        printf("Enter parentheses: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &parentheses);


        if(strcmp(parentheses, "-1") == 0){
            break;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(parentheses); i++){
            if(parentheses[i] == '{' || parentheses[i] == '[' || parentheses[i] == '('){
                push(&stack, parentheses[i]);
            } else if (stack == NULL){
                printf("Invalid parenthesis expression\n");
                break;
            } else if(parentheses[i] == '}' && top(stack) == '{'){
                pop(&stack);
            } else if (parentheses[i] == ']' && top(stack) == '['){
                pop(&stack);
            } else if (parentheses[i] == ')' && top(stack) == '('){
                pop(&stack);
            } else if(parentheses[i] != '{' || parentheses[i] != '[' || parentheses[i] != '(' || parentheses[i] != '}' || parentheses[i] != ']' || parentheses[i] != ']') {
                printf("Invalid parenthesis expression\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        //POP
        if(isempty(stack)){
            printf("Valid parenthesis expression\n");
        } else{
            printf("Invalid parenthesis expression\n");
        }

    }while(1);

    return 0;

}

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses){

    DATA *node = (DATA*) malloc(sizeof(DATA));
    node -> parent = parentheses;
    node -> next = NULL;

    if(!isempty(*stack)) node->next = *stack;
    *stack = node;
}

int isempty(DATA *stack){

    if(stack == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;

}

void pop(DATA **stack){

    DATA *temp = *stack;
    *stack = (*stack)->next;
    free(temp);

}



int top(DATA *stack){

    return stack -> parent; //STACK !ISEMPTY
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> scanf("%[^\n]", &parentheses);
> ```

must be

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", parentheses);
```

notice the space before the '%' to bypass the newline coming from a previous input, without it on the second turn *scanf* does nothing. To detect that case and also any invalid input I encourage you to *always* check the value *scanf* returns.

In case the input has at least 100 characters you write out of *parentheses*, do

```
if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", parentheses) != 1) {
  /* EOF */
  return -1;
}
```

*parentheses* is an array, if you want to use "&" it is specifying the index 0 so &*parentheses[0]*

Note *flag* is unused

When you detect an invalid case you can indicate "Valid parenthesis expression" :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter parentheses: (
Invalid parenthesis expression
Enter parentheses: )
Invalid parenthesis expression
Valid parenthesis expression
```

When the stack is not empty after the *for* you do not free the still present allocated elements, you have memory leaks.

Because you just save characters in the stack it is much more simple and cheaper in memory to just use an array of char. Because the input is limited to 99 (without the final null character) the stack needs to save 99 characters too, and in fact *parentheses* can be used for the stack

A proposal still using your stack, fixing problems and also reducing the number tests and simplifying stack functions :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct data{
  char parent;
  struct data *next;
} DATA;

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses);
int isempty(DATA *stack);
void pop(DATA **stack);
int top(DATA *stack);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  DATA *stack = NULL;
  char parentheses[100];
  char * p;

  while (fputs("Enter parentheses: ", stdout),
         (scanf(" %99[^\n]", parentheses) == 1) && strcmp(parentheses, "-1")) {
    for (p = parentheses; *p; ++p) {
      if  ((*p == '{') || (*p == '[') || (*p == '('))
        push(&stack, *p);
      else {
        char o;

        if (*p == '}')
          o = '{';
        else if (*p == ')')
          o = '(';
        else if (*p == ']')
          o = '[';
        else
          o = 0;

        if (isempty(stack) || (top(stack) != o))
          break;

        pop(&stack);
      }
    }

    if (!isempty(stack) || *p) {
      puts("Invalid parenthesis expression");

      while (! isempty(stack))
        pop(&stack);
    }
    else if (!*p)
      puts("Valid parenthesis expression");
  }

  return 0;
}

void push(DATA **stack, char parentheses) {
    DATA *node = malloc(sizeof(DATA));

    node->parent = parentheses;
    node->next = *stack;
    *stack = node;
}

int isempty(DATA *stack) {
  return (stack == NULL);
}

void pop(DATA **stack) {
  DATA *temp = *stack;

  *stack = (*stack)->next;
  free(temp);
}

int top(DATA *stack) {
  return stack->parent;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter parentheses: ({[]}())
Valid parenthesis expression
Enter parentheses: (
Invalid parenthesis expression
Enter parentheses: )
Invalid parenthesis expression
Enter parentheses: (]
Invalid parenthesis expression
Enter parentheses: -1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thankyou ,I really appreciate your help, thank you so much :)). I'm still trying to understand what the char *p and the char o, so I might be asking some question in this comment, if that's ok :)

Comment: may I ask how does for(p = parentheses; *p; ++p) work ? <br>
especially, what does ++p became ? because it's a char

Comment: @ChristianHalim  *p* is a pointer into *parentheses* to avoid to do *parentheses[i]* all the time. *o* is the expected open character in the top of the stack

Comment: "_*p_" return the character *p* points to, "_++p_" increment the pointer to have it pointing to the next character

Comment: does that means ++p , equal to parentheses[ i ] with i++ ?

Comment: @ChristianHalim yes but in a more efficient way

Comment: @ChristianHalim at any moment "_p - parentheses_" values *i* is you used the index "*i*" rather than the pointer. I think you have to look on internet about pointer in C

Comment: I see, that's new for me.

Comment: @ChristianHalim to understand pointers is very important, without them you are very limited

Comment: wait, how does the for second argument works ? usually with for, the second argument you would use something like i < n

Comment: @ChristianHalim when you read string with *scanf* and for a lot of functions manipulating strings, the string is terminated by a null character, the form "_*p_" in the *for* is  equivalent of "_*p != 0_" or "_*p != '\0'_" whose are equivalent. The form for the loop continuation can be any form, including an empty one (in that case the missing form is considering to value 1/true).

Comment: Alright, thanks once again! I will go and learn about pointer once again